# How to start rails server like windows service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-services, windows-server-2008, thin

I've just finished to write a rails app, and now is(unfortunately) time to deply this app on Windows.
I'm running:

- Windows server 2008
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 3.2.9

Now my web server is Thin, and i want to start it (or something else if it is easier) like a windows service.
I followed 3 or 4 tutorial but it never works and the deadline of the project is everyday nearest.
Hope someone can help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy use [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano)

Or using 3rd party extensions capistrano deploy rails apps to Windows servers :

[capistrano-windows-server](https://github.com/SciMed/capistrano-windows-server)